# Storing latitude and longitude floats as chars with specified precision

Tags: arduino-uno, string, gps, array, float

I am receiving lat and long data from a GPS and want to store these numbers in the middle of a sequence of chars.

E.g. lat = -23.123456

long = 135.123456

I am after something like "Your coordinates are -23.123456,135.123456" as an array of chars.

I have tried:

```
float latitude = -23.123456;
float longitude = 135.123456;

String one = "Your coordinates are ";
String two = ","    
String message = one + latitude + two + longitude;

// Convert String to char array
int str_len = message.length() + 1;
char textmessage[str_len];
message.toCharArray(textmessage,str_len);

Serial.println(textmessage);
```

but the result is: Your coordinates are -023.12,0135.12

How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your GPS actually give you `float`s?  Most output text on a serial port; if you do not need to do numeric operations on the values, perhaps you should just treat them as text all the way through.  Note that if you do use `float`s, their precision is limited, which may well be the cause of what you are seeing with your fake test data.

Comment: Are you sure about your result? I'm trying your code and I get "Your coordinates are -23.123456,135.123456". Just in case you didn't notice, you missing one `;`

Comment: Regarding the limited precision of the float32 format: for numbers in the range \[128, 256) (like your longitude), the [unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) is about 1.53e-5, which translates to a resolution of 1.7 m on the surface of the Earth. Assigning the longitude to a `float` can incur a rounding error as large as half an ulp, or about 85 cm.

Comment: Why not simply use the String member function c_str() to access the char array? `message.c_str()` https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CStr

Answer (score 1):

When formatting serial output is a concern, it's worthwhile to download and use the `Streaming.h` [contributed library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Libraries) that adds some “syntactic sugar” to Arduino C.  That is, at compile time it converts C++-like `<<` Serial stream operators to `Serial.print` statements, without increasing code size.  If you don't have `Streaming.h` installed, you can get [`Streaming5.zip`](http://arduiniana.org/Streaming/Streaming5.zip) from [arduiniana.org](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/).

At present, `Streaming.h` doesn't support `setw()` and `setfill()`, which in ordinary C++ set a field width and a fill character.

However, it does support  four base-conversion specifiers, _HEX, _DEC, _OCT, and _BIN; a _FLOAT function with number of decimal places specified; and `endl`.

Thus, to print  “Your coordinates are -23.123456, 135.123456” one would write:

```
Serial << "Your coordinates are " << _FLOAT(latitude,6) << ", " << _FLOAT(longitude,6) << endl;
```

Note that unlike the `String` class, use of `Streaming.h` does not entail any dynamic memory management – everything it does happens at compile time – and it does not increase code size – it translates stream-style operations into ordinary `.print()` and `.println()` calls.  It should result in somewhat smaller, faster, and more-robust code, by avoidance of `String`.  Use of dynamic memory on small-memory embedded systems can be problematic, and this avoids those problems.

---

*Edit 1a:* As Chris Stratton points out, Arduino floats don't support 9-digit precision.  I think Arduino floating-point arithmetic is intended to comply with [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which sets out standards to be used on modern computers that support floating-point arithmetic.

In the [binary32 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32) used to implement IEEE 754 single-precision binary floating-point, significand precision is 24 bits.  That equates to about 7.22 decimal digits (ie, 24*log₁₀(2)), so for simple calculations, 7-digit accuracy is realistic, more than that is not.

---

*[Part of] Edit 1b:*  In the larger scheme of things perhaps there's no need to create and save a formatted string like that.  It is not useful for computing – the float values are better for that.  It is not needed for communication – another streaming write can be done.

---

*Edit 2 [replaces most of 1b]:* Streaming.h  doesn't build any strings, but just delivers the text of its `<<`-arguments character-by-character to a stream.  However, a [PString class at arduiniana](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/pstring/) can build strings from stream inputs, as in the following example code.

```
#include <Streaming.h>
#include <PString.h>

char buffer[28];
PString pstr(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pstr.begin();     // Empty the buffer
}

void loop() {
  int first=50, second=100;
  pstr.begin();     // Empty the buffer
  pstr << 'X' << first << 'Y' << second << 'T';
  pstr += " hihi ";
  pstr << millis() << endl;
  Serial << pstr;
  delay(1000);
}
```

Here's what some of its output to Serial looks like:

```
X50Y100T hihi 263198
X50Y100T hihi 264199
X50Y100T hihi 265199
X50Y100T hihi 266201
X50Y100T hihi 267201
X50Y100T hihi 268201
```

What the sample of code does is first initialize a string buffer, then build part of a character string using streaming operator `<<`, then part of it using concatenation, then some more with `<<`, then print the string.  Note that the strings involved here are in fixed buffers, rather than dynamically allocated buffers like the String class uses.

Comment: It is possible you may do better than the code in the question, but you *will not* get the desired precision from an ATmega-based Arduino Uno's `float`.

Comment: Thanks! However I need to save this printed sequence as an array of chars to be used later in the code. Can this be done from the printed Serial <<... ?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, reflected in Edit 1a

Comment: @Anwar, please see Edit 1b

Comment: Although the streaming library is a nice syntax candy, you do not need it to specify the number of digits to print. You can also `Serial.print(latitude, 6);`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, true.   But if one is doing a bunch of formatting (ie, the “When formatting serial output is a concern” case), Streaming.h helps keep the code compact and more clear than a long series of prints.  (My initial read of the question, possibly wrong, suggested formatting issues rather than getting-a-string issues.)

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. However I am after a solution that does not read the string from the Serial window (as suggested in Edit 1b) as I will eventually use this module without being connected to a computer.

Comment: @Anwar, edit 2 explains how to build a string, using `PString` class.  In any case, 1a and 1b were about how to send data via Serial, with no suggestion about "read the string from the Serial window"